# Prove b is the g.l.b of B

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Let R be a partial order on A, $B \subseteq A$ and $b \in B$

Prove that if b is the smallest element of B, then it is also g.l.b of B

**ATTEMPT**

Let b be smallest element of B. So $\forall x \in B,  bRx$. This means b is lower bound. Now let $c$ be another lower bound of B. so cRb. Also we have bRx. So cRx. But this would mean that c is smallest element which is a contradiction.
Is this correct ?

Thanks

Comment: What is x??????

Comment: There is no contradiction. It's just that, if $c$ is any lower bound of $B$, from $cRb$ it already follows that $b$ is the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly b is a lower bound of B.
Let x be a lower bound of B. Since b in B, xRb.
Thus b is the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a partial order on $A$; let $B \subseteq A$; let $b$ be the smallest element in $B$.  Then $b$ is a lower bound for $B$.  Suppose $l \in A$ is a lower bound for $B$.  Then $lRb'~\forall b' \in B$.  In particular, $lRb$ since $b \in B$. If $l \neq b$, then $l$ is smaller than $b$, so it is not a greatest lower bound for $B$ since $b$ is a lower bound for $B$.  Hence, $b$ is the greatest lower bound for $B$.

Comment: Sir, may i know what is wrong in my proof ? Thanks

Comment: You have established that $c$ is a lower bound for $B$.  What you want to establish is that if $c$ is a lower bound for $B$, then $c = b$.

Comment: How does this proves that b is greatest lower bound

Comment: It proves that any lower bound of $B$ is at least $b$.

Comment: i am not sure i follow

Comment: don't we have to make cases when b'belongs to B and when not?

Comment: We are given $b \in B$.  The [*infimum* (*greatest lower bound*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of a partially ordered set is an element that has the property that is less than or equal to all the elements in that set.  Thus, we need to establish that if $b' \in B$ is  any element of $B$, then $b \leq b'$.  By showing that a lower bound $b'  \in B$ satisfies $b = b'$, we get $b \leq b'$.

Comment: But b' may not belong to B as lower bound can or cnnot belong to set

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I should have specified that $b' \in B$.

Comment: No, you have written that, i say, if $b' \notin B$ then what ?

Comment: Your questions made me rethink my proof.  We need to establish that any lower bound for $B$ is at most $b$.  You did this in your attempt.  However, unless $c \in B$, you cannot say that $c$ is the smallest element of $B$.

Comment: " If l \neq b then then l is smaller than b, so its not glb " . how come ?

Comment: If $l$ is smaller than $b$, then it cannot be the greatest lower bound since $b$ is a larger upper bound than $l$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $b$ is the smallest element of $B$. Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $B$. Clearly $b \in L$, so $L \neq \emptyset$. Now let $y \in L$ be arbitrary. Then $\forall x \in B (y R x)$, since $y$ is a lower bound of $B$. Letting $x = b$ in particular, we have $ y R b$. Since $y \in L$ was arbitrary, $\forall y \in L (y R b)$. Thus, $b$ is the largest element of L. Since $b$ is the largest element of the set of lower bounds $L$, $b$ is the greatest lower bound of $B$.